# LaTeX rendering broken in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab, mathjax

Recently LaTeX formula rendering has stopped working for me in Jupyter.

Example: The following formula...

```
$$
T(P, \hat{b}) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^n b_t}
$$
```

turns out like this:

[image]

I don't know where to start debugging.

Versions:

- jupyterlab                3.0.16             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

Comment: It was displayed correctly in my environment. jupyerlab 3.2.1 python 3.8.10

Comment: You can start by upgrading to a newer version, and listing all extensions you have installed (`jupyter labextension list`).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it installing [jupyterlab-mathjax3](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-mathjax3/). It can be done by writing `%pip install jupyterlab-mathjax3` in a cell in a JupyterLab notebook.